# How do I find the closest parent name matching a regular expression?

Tags: git

At the very root of my project I have the `master` branch, from here I can have branches with the names `Release-*` (`Release` branches come from `Master`). It is possible to branch from the release branches. I am trying to find a way to find whether the current branch I am on came from either a release branch or from master.

Comment: Most git repos have only one root commit (a commit with no parents).  If your git repo has only one root commit, then your branch came from the master.  It also came from a release branch. (Indeed, it came from all of the release branches, and every other branch.).  Perhaps the question you are trying to ask is whether or not the merge base of your branch and a particular release branch is on the master branch (eg, is an ancestor of the current tip of master)

Answer (score 0):

You can check weather the head branch out from a master or a release by using `git log`. For an example, I am using my own repo from [here](https://github.com/rafathasan/fund-at-first-sight).

```
git log --graph --oneline
```

Output:

```
* b452743 (HEAD -> master, tag: v0.1.2-beta, origin/master, origin/HEAD) update: close driver at the end
* a150370 fix: remove spaces from header line
* cb7d6f5 (tag: v0.1.1-beta) chore: remove folder from gitignore
* 968db4f add: example directory file
* ab65070 (tag: v0.1.0-beta) Update README.md
* ddfa102 Update README.md
* 20a3308 Update README.md
* 7500552 Update requirements
* 44220ff Fix argument passing in Listerner
* 05e7697 Fix remove unused config
* 726bea0 Fix #1
* 9ad4e4c Add webdriver, no longer need to download chromedriver
* 03bfc94 Update README.md
* 82cb75f Update README.md
* b0d10d0 Update README.md
* 54f55c4 Create README.md
* 3f57df5 add requirements
* 88d5276 add README
* eb29696 update gitignore
* 56a06ad update key listerner
* df2398e update main.py
* 35fb259 update .gitignore
* 0e615f3 add utils
* 142314c add utils
* 6a548b7 add config
* 378ff5e add .gitignore
* 12c372d add placeholder main.py
```

Here I can see that the head is on master and also it's a release by looking at the `tag: v0.1.2-beta`. If we look at the previous commits we will see the other release tags `tag: v0.1.1-beta` and `tag: v0.1.0-beta`.

Comment: I have edited my answer please check if this is what you are looking for and please let me know if it doesn't work for you. Thanks!

Comment: My terminal output when I run this command is a giant Tree, not a nice line by line output like you have.

Comment: Try this `git log --oneline --tags --no-walk`. This will only show you the tags/releases.